# Google account integration in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, google, online-accounts

I'm new to Ubuntu and I recently installed 12.10. Since I'm having problems with online accounts (including Google, which doesn't seem to integrate anything in my OS) I would like to know what exactly a Google account is used for. Does it add GMail into the messaging menu (without gm-notify or similar apps) and syncs my google calendar with the default Ubuntu calendar?

Comment: You will be able to find your google drive and picasa data in the dash.

Answer (score 1):

At least for now, **online accounts** merely help you use the default **Empathy** chat program to connect with your Facebook, Google Talk, etc. friends. It doesn't sync with GMail or Google Calendar. For instance, you can use **Unity Mail** for your Gmail accounts, but it requires you to enter GMail account details again as it's not linked to online accounts.

Comment: Thanks, I hope they will push this further in the next releases.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely certain this answers all of your question ... I use my Google account for consolidating 3 email accounts, then access all three with iMap in Thunderbird; web access too. Additionally Calendar and Google Drive are available. I installed Chromium as a browser so all browser settings are synchronized to my 2 pc's. Additionally the gmail consolidation of calendar and email keeps my iPhone synchronized. Possibly this is all available using FireFox - I just never tried.